# VBA Column Hide/Unhide not working all of a sudden

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that has always worked for me prior to now.

It simply looks at cell A1 (which is a name) and compares it to the data in Row1 and hides/unhides as necessary.

Out of nowhere today, when I remove data from A1, it unhides everything EXCEPT columns I & K, they stay hidden and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

To make things more interesting, if I select a blank selection from the drop-down in A1, it unhides all columns, but as soon as I click the delete button on A1, it hides I & K again. Help!

Here is the code from the module:

```
Sub HideColumns_AC_SCORECARD()
Dim col As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each col In Worksheets("AC Scorecard").Range("F:BG").Columns
        col.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
     If Application.CountIf(col, Range("A1")) = 0 Then
         col.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
     End If
Next col
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is the code from the sheet in question:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Intersect(target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then HideColumns_AC_SCORECARD
End Sub
```

This has always worked perfectly for me before today.

Comment: Are there Zeros `0` in column I & K? then this is your issue. Zeros may be counted as empty cells (they are zero too).

Comment: Is `AC Scorecard` always the activesheet?  `If Application.CountIf(col, Range("A1"))` is looking at A1 on the activesheet - not necessarily `AC Scorecard`.  Saying that, if it only fires on the `Worksheet_Change` event then "AC AC Scorecard" has to be active.

Comment: I & K are actually the only columns that DON'T have 0's... so I really don't understand. The 0 in the formula is only referring to  A1 anyway is it not? I've never had the issue before where it mattered what was in in cells as far as data goes, but obviously there is something to the fact that columns I & K are the only ones with no 0's in any cell

Comment: So I just did some additional testing and it's definitely the lack of 0's in those columns that are causing them to stay hidden (though it's still very odd that selecting a black selection from the drop down works fine, but when you actually "delete" the data from A1 it then hides those 2 columns). Can anyone think of a way to amend my formula so it works as intended? I just want all columns unhidden when A1=blank/0 and all columns hidden, except the one when A1 (a persons name) matches a cell in the column (which will always be in row 1, if that matters)

Comment: @PatrickManning That odd behavior comes because selecting a `vbNullString` or `""` out of a list is a text but not zero `0` but a blank cell is considered as zero and not as NullString. So to summarize: `vbNullstring = "" = (Text) <> 0 = EmptyCell = (Number)`